# How do you serialize/parse a nested JSON array in Flutter/Dart if it has no name/key

Tags: json, parsing, serialization, dart, flutter

I'm working with a RESTful API that seems to be working and used in other applications that gives me something like this:

```
 "notes": [
    [
      {
        "automaticNote": false,
        "contactId": 0,
        "caseFileId": 0,
        "dateCreated": "2019-05-02",
        "deletedTime": "2019-05-02T19:31:54.588Z"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

The double pair of square brackets means that one pair of the square brackets has no name/key associated with it. To make matters worse, `notes` is itself nested in some complex JSON.

I tried using [JSON to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) but it throws an error. So really my question is, how do I serialize a JSON array that has no key/name?

I'd normally do it like this:

```
    class Note {
  bool automaticNote;
  int contactId;
  int caseFileId;
  String dateCreated;
  String deletedTime;

  Note(
      {this.automaticNote,
      this.contactId,
      this.caseFileId,
      this.dateCreated,
      this.deletedTime});

  Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    automaticNote = json['automaticNote'];
    contactId = json['contactId'];
    caseFileId = json['caseFileId'];
    dateCreated = json['dateCreated'];
    deletedTime = json['deletedTime'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['automaticNote'] = this.automaticNote;
    data['contactId'] = this.contactId;
    data['caseFileId'] = this.caseFileId;
    data['dateCreated'] = this.dateCreated;
    data['deletedTime'] = this.deletedTime;
    return data;
  }
}
```

But the double JSON array is throwing me off (and again, `notes` itself is nested in a more complex JSON object but for the sake of simplicity I did not include the whole thing here).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the case of you saving automaticNote;

automaticNote = json['notes'][0][0]['automaticNote'];

This offers the key for notes which has an array where your data is at the first point or index 0 (of notes hence [0]) and within that array there is another array which has your data. Again it's the first array item so, [0] and then you're finally at the level with your data so you then use your key for automaticNote, ['automaticNote'].

```
Note.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    automaticNote = json[0][0]['automaticNote'];
    contactId = json[0][0]['contactId'];
    caseFileId = json[0][0]['caseFileId'];
    dateCreated = json[0][0]['dateCreated'];
    deletedTime = json[0][0]['deletedTime'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

After decoding, `notes` is a member of some `Map<String, dynamic>` as usual. Let's call that `m`.

So `m['notes']` is a list, who's first member, `m['notes'][0]` is also a list. Its first member, `m['notes'][0][0]` is another `Map<String, dynamic>`, which is what you need for your constructor.

You should therefore be able to use:

```
Note n = Note.fromJson(m['notes'][0][0]);
```

Comment: Wow I think this might solve it! I'll give it a try and let you know. Thank you so much!